# SoapUI Xml Datasource reading null row

Tags: xml, groovy, datasource, soapui

I'm using XML data source in soapUI.
Only one cell in "Selected" row have a value = selected, another cells in "Selected" row  are blank.
For example:

```
Selected              Value

                      12210
                      12813
selected              12213
                      12214
                      12215
                      12216
```

In my example I need to get value "12213" using groovy script.

If I tried

```
def Solected = context.expand('${DataSource1#selected}')
def Value = context.expand('${DataSource1#value}')
```

I receive result = 12216

Could someone please let me know how to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you retrieve the datasource rows, the last row is returned.
you need to run the testcase with a dataloop to read all lines.

If you only want the selected lines, in your groovy script, you can make a if statement to go directly to the dataloop if the selected field is empty.

```
if(context.expand('${DataSource1#selected}') == ""){
    testRunner.gotoStepByName('DataLoop')
}
```

Comment: I'm not good in data loop and data source. Can you explain in more detail? I have test case "DataSource1" witch consists of a table as in my example above.

Comment: It might be better if you explain what you are trying to accomplish here. Why are you using a datasource in the first place? What he is saying above is if the selected properly has no value, then jump to your datasource loop which will iterate to the next row of data and try again. You can read about them here. https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/data-driven/tutorials/functional/loop.html